# What did i do wrong here? Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, referenceerror

```
function look() {
var desc = "";
    switch(currentLoc) {
        case 0 = name.Starting Room; 
            break;
        case 1 = name.Forest;
            break; 
        case 2 = name.Seagulls;   
            break;
        case 3 = name.Ocean; 
            break;
        case 4 = name.Resort;     
            break;
        case 5 = name.Rock;
            break;
        case 6 = name.Wise Turtle;
            break;
        case 7 = name.Palm Tree;
            break;
        case 8 = name.Iglo;
            break;
        case 9 = name.sandBurrow;
            break;
        case 10 = name.End;
            break;
    default: desc = "You cannot go that way";
}
disable_btns();
```

}

this is for a project of mine. I dont know how to fix this problem. 
If you want to see the full code cause this used to work till i added in a matrix and changed the locations format for my game so im pretty sure it has something to do with that but i dont know what. you can take a look at the full code here https://github.com/rileyjgr/Games if you have the time. Thanks for the help >.< i dont know what i fucked up with.

Comment: Your code syntax is fundamentally wrong. I suggest you read the reference for [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: That is not how to use `switch`.

Comment: This is how I taught to by my professor...

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `:` after each `case` instead of a `=`.

I'm guessing you meant this:

```
case 2: desc = name.Seagulls;
```

However, it would seem that you could be better served by using an Array.

```
var data = [
    name.StartingRoom, 
    name.Forest,
    name.Seagul,
    name.Resort
];
```

and then

```
var desc = data[currentLoc];
```

Comment: Okay but if i use that array. How am i supposed to identify it so the matrix can folloow it or is that not nessary?

Comment: All I know is that you have numeric indices mapped to values. It would seem that whatever `name` represents could have an Array of values instead of individual properties for each value. So you'd do `name.values[currentLoc]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your structure should probably look like, assuming you have a `name` Object. Note that `switchArg` must match 0-10 to return one of your `name` Object properties.

```
var name = {'Starting Room':'home', Forest:'trees', Seagulls:'birds', Ocean:'Pacific', Resort:'town', Rock:'and Roll', 'Wise Turtle':'slow', 'Palm Tree':'coconut', Iglo:'ice', sandBurrow:'What', End:'of Days'};
function returnFromSwitch(switchArg){
  switch(switchArg) {
    case 0:
      return name['Starting Room'];
    case 1:
      return name.Forest;
    case 2:
      return name.Seagulls;   
    case 3:
      return name.Ocean; 
    case 4:
      return name.Resort;     
    case 5: 
      return name.Rock;
    case 6:
      return name['Wise Turtle'];
    case 7:
      return name['Palm Tree'];
    case 8:
      return name.Iglo;
    case 9:
      return name.sandBurrow;
    case 10:
      return name.End;
    default:
      return 'Keep on Learning.';
  }
}
console.log(returnFromSwitch(5)); // 'and Roll'
```

Note, that if you used `disable_btns()` in this function, which I purposely left out, it would have to be executed before the function returns any value. When using a switch inside a function there may be no need to use `break`. If those are the only results you can just `return` the value.